# Why is my permission denied when I try to create a MySQL database?

Tags: mysql, database, unix, terminal

I am root user on my computer, but when I use the command:

`mysql> CREATE DATABASE foo;`

it gives me error:

`CREATE: Permission denied`

Answer (score 1):

It's because your user doesn't have the [`CREATE` privilege](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_create). As the root user, try this:

`GRANT CREATE ON *.* TO 'user'@'hostname';`

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't matter who are you for the system, if you want to login in mysql as root you have to do it explicitly:

```
mysql -u root –p
```